# Filter NSArray by evaluating neighbor objects

Tags: objective-c, filter, nsarray, nspredicate

I have got the following problem:
I have an ordered NSArray of objects which each contain a NSDate and a NSNumber.
I want to filter the array, so that from consecutive objects with the same value only the FIRST and the LAST appear in the filteredArray.

Example:

```
13:01  7.0
13:02  7.1 (1st) 
13:03  7.1 (2nd, to be filtered)
13:04  7.1 (3rd)
13:05  7.2
13:06  7.2
13:07  7.3 (1st)
13:08  7.3 (2nd, to be filtered)
13:09  7.3 (3rd, to be filtered)
13:10  7.3 (4th)
13:11  7.1
```

I suppose this cannot be done with a NSPredicate, so what is the most efficient way to accomplish this?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's already sorted, how about simply iterating through the array, adding or replacing the object as needed? Something like:

```
NSMutableArray *myFilteredArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:myArray.count];
for (id object in myArray)
{
    if (myFilteredArray.count>1)
    {
        id secondLastObject = [myFilteredArray objectAtIndex:myFilteredArray.count-2];
        id lastObject = myFilterdArray.lastObject;
        if ([[secondLastObject number] isEqualToNumber:[object number] && [[lastObject number] isEqualToNumber:[object number]])
        {
            [myFilteredArray removeLastObject];
        }
    }
    [myFilteredArray addObject:object];
}
```

Seems like that should be pretty efficient to me, only one pass through the array.

Comment: Yes, a naive approach would be to divide the array into subarrays with same values and join them again by taking the first and last of each of them. But this seems not to be very performant..

Comment: Yes, it should be "if (myFilteredArray.count>1)". Now it's really good, thank you! Please remove the first part of your answer (up to "take two")

Comment: I found a small bug: One should compare not only the second last element's value but also the last one's: if (([secondLastObject value] == [object value]) && ([lastObject value] == [object value])) { .. }

Comment: Added it to the answer, must have been thrown off by the general pattern of the numbers always increasing and assumed that I only needed to check the second last one.

Comment: Another slight optimization: One could use a "id tempObject;" and get rid of unnecessary adding and removing to the array. Instead of removing, set tempObject to nil, and instead of "addObject:object" let's say: if (tempObject) {[myFilteredArray addObject: tempObject];}; tempObject = object;

Answer (score 0):

My practice would be:

1. Go throw the array and check if there are three equal numbers
2. If there are three equal numbers then find out how many
3. Delete all numbers except the first and the last

I'm not sure if you are asking just for the practice or need real code but let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Yeah, something like that, but it should be possible to do that with only one iteration over the elements of the unfiltered array, maybe by keeping the last two elements in variables.

Answer (score 0):

Naive approach:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayList = [NSMutableArray new];

// Split array
NSMutableArray *currentSubArray = nil;
float lastValue = 0.0f;
for (MyObject *obj in myArray) {
    if ((obj.value != lastValue) || !currentSubArray) {
        currentSubArray = [NSMutableArray new];
        [arrayList addObject:currentSubArray];
        lastValue = obj.value;
    }
    [currentSubArray addObject:obj];
}

// Join again with first/last objects only
NSMutableArray *myFilteredArray = [NSMutableArray new];
for (NSArray* subArray in arrayList) {
    [myFilteredArray addObject:[subArray firstObject]];
    if (subArray.count>1) {
        [myFilteredArray addObject:[subArray lastObject]];
    }
}
```